# My sprite walking animation code doesn't work at all

Tags: animation, sprites, game-maker, jumping

This is my first time doing code for a game so I followed some online tutorials.

When I got to the walking and the jumping animation I just can't get it to work whatever I do.

I tried multiple codes but it doesn't work.

My animation code right now:

```
//animation    
if (!place_meeting(x,y+1,Owhitetile))
{
    sprite_index = Scute_character_jump_right;
    image_speed = 0;
    if(sign(vspeed)  < 0) image_index = 0;
}
else 
{
    image_speed = 1;
    if(hspeed == 0)
    {
        sprite_index = Scute_character_right;
    }
    else
    {
        sprite_index = Scute_character_walk;
    }
}
```

All my code so far

```
//player imput
key_left = keyboard_check (vk_left);
key_right = keyboard_check (vk_right);
key_jump = keyboard_check_pressed (vk_space);

//calculate movement
var move = key_right - key_left;

hspeed = move * walksp;
vspeed = vspeed + grv;

if (place_meeting(x,y+1,Owhitetile)) and (key_jump)
{
    vspeed=-7;
}

//horizontal colision
if (place_meeting(x+hspeed,y,Owhitetile))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x+sign(hspeed),y,Owhitetile))
    {
        x = x + sign(hspeed);
    }
    hspeed = 0;
}
x = x + hspeed;

//vertical colision
if (place_meeting(x,y+vspeed,Owhitetile))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vspeed),Owhitetile))
    {
        y = y + sign(vspeed);
    }
    vspeed = 0;
}
y = y + vspeed;


//player death
if (place_meeting(x,y+vspeed,Ospikes))
{

   instance_destroy()
   game_restart()

}

//animation

if (!place_meeting(x,y+1,Owhitetile))
{
    sprite_index = Scute_character_jump_right;
    image_speed = 0;
    if(sign(vspeed)  < 0) image_index = 0;
}
else 
{
    image_speed = 1;
    if(hspeed == 0)
    {
        sprite_index = Scute_character_right;
    }
    else
    {
        sprite_index = Scute_character_walk;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what you expect to happen and what happens instead? "It doesn't work" doesn't provide much information, meaning people will have a hard time figuring out *why* it doesn't work and you will be less likely to get an answer. Pictures or videos/gifs are helpful as well. Also, it would help if you told us what engine and technology you're working with.

Comment: Hey ce, Seeing that this is GameMaker, I think the problem could lie on the sprite rather than the code, could you show the three `Scute_character` sprites?